# Supplying power to two devices at the same time

Tags: power-supply

I have two devices that individually require 5 V, 3 A, does this mean I can use a single 5 V, 3 A DC supply to supply the both of them or would the supply need to be capable of 5 V, 6 A in order to power them both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a power supply capable of 5 V and *at least* 6 A. You need to have some margin. 
I'd go for 6.5-7 A just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the single 5V 3A DC supply to supply both of them but not at the same time.  To power them at the same time, the supply must be capable of 5V 6A.